# Is any way to manage direction of array modifier?

Tags: modifiers

Good day. I wonder, can I place column of 5 (for example) squares than change direction to 90 degrees and continue that row (so I'll got that figure |_ ) ? I want to use just standard modifiers.

Comment: @moonboots in that case i'll get 2x2 matrix, not |_. And if I'll want to change "thickness" of that |_, everything will break I suppose. I think, your way can work if every modifier will affect on initial mesh, but they affect on each other, so maybe I don't know something?

Comment: yes you're right, my bad

Comment: @Сергей I'm sorry, I have no time to elaborate my solution, but maybe you can simply take the blend file and play around with. It has its limitations and you could definitely expand it to have more possibilities... Link: [L-shape.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUPXlB0_6Ry8Tzqe7ePETiscvObMgQmW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann wow, it's cool but too complicated for me. I can't understand what's happening here but the result is perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you are:

[image]

[image]

You can just use mesh lines as "grid" and instance cubes on that lines.

Comment: Cool, thank you! But I think it needs to be two nodes before second mesh line (object info and vector add) because geometry is overlapping each other, so we need an offset for start position of second mesh line.

Comment: You are right!!!